# IE 11 (with standard settings) forgets login session between restarts

Tags: internet-explorer, session

IE 11, Windows 7

I rarely use IE but I noticed that on some but not all sites when I quit IE and restart I have to login again.

Because I use it so infrequently my settings are all "standard", the Microsoft defaults.

coursera.org: IE remembers the session

edx.org: Upon restart I get the login page again (Chrome and Firefox remember the session and upon restart I get my edx.org tabs loaded as it should be)

I'm just generally curious why that would happen, I don't really use IE. To clarify: I'm asking which setting or problem IE specifically has for this to occur, as a developer I know how cookies and sessions work...